# High gain problem

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, amplifier, gain

I have a question about amplifiers. If I want to put and amplification stage after and after and after other one, why can't I have practically an infinite gain? what is the reason that doesn't allow that? What limiting factors come into play ?

Comment: that question is also mine hahaha but now i want to know the reason that doesn't allow this gain to be infinite

Comment: Is there a reason that stops that/ What makes you think there is? Post what you'we tried, inc. schematics, what yu expected, and what you found instead, and ask why your expectations and measurements didn't match, and you might have a half decent question.

Comment: Infinite gain needs infinite number of limited gain stages. Unfortunately our planet has only a finite number of atoms for you to use for the gain stages. It doesn't help if you were able to use also Moon and Mars for your project.

Comment: Lots of op-amps come with open-loop gain in the region of 100,000. But why do you need that much gain? Remember the gain applies to noise as well. The other relevant limits are the *output* capabilities of the opamp. Think for a moment: what would the output of your "nearly infinite" gain look like?

Comment: for real the gain i need to get it's 460 V/V, but i only got to a maximum of 52 :(

Comment: Note that if you put two of those in series you'll get a gain of more than 2500. However, since you refuse to give a schematic of what you've done, your question is pretty much unanswerable.

Answer (score 4):

You can make arbitrarily large gain by cascading amplifiers.  However, there will be undesirable effects.

If the amps are DC-coupled, then the DC offsets get multiplied by the gains too, particularly those of early stages.

Noise is always added when you manipulate a signal.  The signal to noise ratio will therefore get progressively worse.

Eventually with enough gain, the DC offset and/or noise is so large that it covers the full output swing range of the last amplifier, making the result useless.

Comment: thanks for this answer! i understood what you said, i made this question because i have to make an amplifier with mosfets, and get a gain of 460 [V/V], do you have any idea how could this be possible? thank you very much!

Comment: @Voni: That's a totally different question, and too broad as you state it.  Post a separate question, explain what you need to accomplish, what you have tried so far, and what *specifically* you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Noise and offsets can limit the practical gain as Olin has covered .If the proposed Amplifier does not have to respond down to DC then simple   interstage coupling caps can sort the offset problem .There is also unwanted feedback which if positive will make the proposed amplifier chain unstable and if negative will reduce gain .Unwanted feedback gets worse as F goes up .This means that the practical gain of your proposed cascade will be higher at lower frequencies.PCB layout and shielding become much more important as you demand more gain by adding more stages .

Comment: Infinite gain applied to infinitesimal accidental feedback is an important limitation.   It's not an amplifier any more, if feedback can come to dominate the input signal.

Answer (score -1):

[fundamental limit to amplification is derived at end of answer]

As a teenager I built dozens of 6 and 7 and 8 stage bipolar amplifiers; inevitably, until I learned about 5,00UF capacitors and 100_ohm resistors used to low-pass-filter the VDD to first couple stages, those amplifiers would oscillate.

More recently I installed 8 AM radios ---- heterodynes ---- on one silicon chip, to examine the substrate coupling. Topology was
(1) differential pickup from the substrate region of interest
(2) some moderate gain --- 10dB --- at that high frequency
(3) carefully laidout shielded differential wiring into a down-conversion mixer, using a LocalOscillator frequency from off-chip
(4) gain of 20dB/60dB/100dB at the IntermediateFrequency

There was no oscillation, from LO of 5MHz up to 500MHz where the mixer conversion efficiency dropped off (I was not burning enough current to sustain full mixer efficiency above 500MHz).

However---- if there was no LocalOscillator input from offchip, the selected signal-chain would be oscillating, because the entire signal-chain was at the SAME FREQUENCY.

The amateur-radio community has radios capable of boosting nanovolt signals up to 1 volt or more, to drive a loudspeaker; these radios are double or triple conversion ( at least the schematics I recall from old ARRL manuals).

Here is a fundamental limit to amplification

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fItt6E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What happens with 50 ohm load, 10nH inductor (in the GND pin of amplifier, that pin shared by both input and output), and Av = 100X?
FreqOsc = 50 / ( 6.28 * 100 * 1e-8Henry) = 50 / 6.28e-6 = 8MHz